# Angular [$injector:modulerr] error with ui-router

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web

I have this code

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router']);
app.config([ '$stateProvider', '$urlRouteProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouteProvider) {}]);
```

In HTML

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
```

and it gives me

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Here is uglify output

```
var app=angular.module("myapp",["ui.router"]);app.config(["$stateProvider","$urlRouteProvider",function(r,e){}]);
```

How I load this files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="minjs/all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its '$urlRouterProvider' not '$urlRouteProvider'.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Typos like that just freak me out.

Comment: I’m happy to help!!